# Grief with Gradle and Maven repository for Android builds

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have been having endless grief with Gradle for Android builds after I had to format my Macbook Pro for some stupid corporate domain migration. I have been using Gradle (both off the command line and with Android Studio) to build my projects for over an year now, and never had problems till the fresh install. I spent countless hours over the weekend trying to fix this, but with no luck, and I'm literally on the verge of tearing my hair out! Here is what I'm stuck with:

## Gradle builds have slowed to a crawl

I have a multi-project (or multi-module in Android terms) project which used to take around 2 minutes for a clean build - plus uploading archives to the (local) Maven repository. Now,the Gradle configuration phase takes around **8 minutes**! Nothing has changed, for after the fresh setup on the Mac, I just took a pull of the sources from the Github repo, and I'm building using the gradle wrapper (as before) which uses version `2.2.1`. Not sure if this matters, but the Gradle version on my machine is `2.6`. I use Maven - not for builds, but for the local M2 repository, and the Maven version is `3.3.3`. Both Maven and Gradle were installed using Homebrew. The Gradle runtimes are the same whether of the command line or using Android Studio. I'm using Android Studio version `1.4-beta4`. Here are the things I have set up:

- I have set up the Maven `settings.xml` to point the local Maven repository to the default location `${user.home}/.m2/repository
- I have set up Google repository using Android Studio and the Support repository (my project needs Play services and the support library)
- We need to upload the archives to the corporate Maven repository on our build servers; to sidestep this, I use the `gradle.properties` to define the repository URL to be the local M2 repository that's set up in the Maven settings
- The project defines Android build tools version `1.1.0`, and while this is an older version, I tried with the latest `1.3.1` with no luck on the build times
- Possibly related: my Mac Pro uses a good ol' HDD, not the newer solid-state storage. While that can impact build times, the disk was not updated during the format, and also, I presume that it shouldn't result in such multiple orders of magnitude impact

## Failure in resolving artifacts from local M2 repo

The primary project that I work on is a library, and we have test clients that we use to verify functionality. The library and test clients are maintained as separate projects in the Github repo. To not have to make *any* changes in my local development setup, I prefer to deploy the artifacts from my library to my local M2 repo, and then have the test client define and resolve the dependency locally. I accomplish this using the global `gradle.properties` to override the repository URL (point it to the local M2 repo). This worked just fine till the disk format, but is broken since. Gradle is never able to resolve the artifacts, but I can see them in the local M2 repo. I have googled high and low (on Gradle forums, here on SO), but cannot seem to figure out what I'm missing or doing wrongly. As a work-around, I added the test client as a module to the library project, and am building it as a single multi-module project. BTW, even with this, I still run into the slow Gradle build times problem that I mentioned above.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You could run `gradlew --profile x` to get a detailed report of where the time is being spent.

Comment: You might get better attention from others if you tried to separate this into separate, smaller, questions about one topic at a time. This site's format is not good for troubleshooting, so good answers will depend on having small, well-structured, questions. It might also be smart to lay off the emotional comments as they might not serve as well to motivate others as you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There's one little bit I'm still not able to grok, but that aside here is what was wrong:

## Slow gradle builds

The project's `build.gradle` file had declared a dependency on our corporate SCM Maven repository. I replicate whatever dependencies my project actually needs in the local M2 repo. Once I replaced this with a file URL pointing to the local M2 repo, Gradle build times dropped to the earlier 30-40 seconds. The part I'm still confused about is that even with the remote repo, Gradle should have downloaded the artifacts once and cached them in the Gradle cache. Still need to figure out why it's not doing that.

## Failure in resolving artifacts from local M2 repo

This was a bad error on my part. In my `gradle.properties` I'd listed the `SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL` override as `/Users/me/.m2/repository` (with `me` replaced with the username). I missed the `file://` prefix here. I'm somewhat surprised that Gradle didn't call it out, and instead deployed the artifacts at the directory pointed by `/Users/me/.m2/repository`, but may be I don't understand how this works so well. Once I added the `file://` prefix, all the test project builds worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

so there are a few Problems you  got to adress: 
1. gradle is not resolving the artefacts in the local repository 
- maybe it corrupted during the formating (Setup a test Project using maven for 
its build only, specify some existing dependencies if you want to verify).
A fresh setup of the repo could resolve this.
2. gradle build is slow
Well, without further Information hard to troubleshoot. Did you refresh your dependencies, clean up the Cache, have enough free disk space in the GRADLE_USER_HOME?

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention in the original question, but I already tried deleting the Gradle cache (`${user.home}/.gradle/caches`), deleting the local M2 repo. Also, I have the `M2_HOME` variable set correctly to point to the Maven installation. The versions are: Gradle - 2.6, though the Gradle-wrapper I use for my builds is on 2.2.1; Maven - 3.3.3; JDK 1.7 

I'm using an Mid-2012 version of Macbook Pro running OS Yosemite 10.10.5.